# Multiple parameters for 2 models

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have 2 models which are merged into a single model. This single model is created as follows:

```
fm = layers.Concatenate()([m1.output, m2.output])

# create dense layer for fusion
t = layers.Dense(143, activation='relu')(fm )

d = layers.Dropout(0.5)(t)
# create softmax layer for predictions
output = layers.Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax')(d)

# create model from all those layers :)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[ m1.input, m2.input], outputs=output)
```

This single model accepts the input from the two models : these two models are

First model - 2 input parameters `tx[0] and tx[1]`
Second model - 1 input parameter `vx`

and a common Y `vy`

Here's how I try to use them:

```
history = model.fit(
    [ 
            [ np.array(tx[0]), np.array(tx[1]) ], 
             np.array(vx)
    ],
             np.array(vy), verbose = 1,
                    
           validation_data = (
    [ 
               [ np.array(txv[0]), np.array(txv[1]) ],
                np.array(tvv)
    ],
                np.array(vy)),
                    
           epochs = 1200,
           batch_size = 128,
           callbacks = [es, mcp_save])
```

So my first model has 2 parameters and my second one has one parameter. They both have a common y.

But the problem is that for some reason the first parameters end up being inputted for the second model. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your model correctly, it has three inputs layers and you only mentioned two in your final model.
Use the variable name of each of the two input_layers of the first model instead of m1.input.

```
#the two input layers of the first Model m1:
inputA = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,))
inputB = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,))

#the input layer of the second Model m2:
inputC = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,))
#after merging the two models m1 and m2 into one Model model :
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputA, inputB , inputC], outputs=output)
```

Comment: Hi! What is FIRST_INPUT_NAME, a string? It doesn't work like that. I tried creating input layers but that didn't work because those new input layers are not connected to my model

Comment: My model has 3 input layers which come from 2 different models. One of the models has 2 input layers and the other has 1 input layer. The final model uses those 3 input layers but I can't seem to input them

Comment: so in conclusion....I had to globally save the Input objects and then use them the way you described. there was no way to get the objects from the models themselves. Really weird stuff. If you edit your answer to include that information that would be great! thnks

Comment: I Mean by "FIRST_INPUT_name, SECOND_INPUT_name" the variables that refer to the input layer objects of the first model

Comment: Yeah, that was what I did as well..but i find it surprising that i can't access the individual input layers through the model. :)

Comment: yy = m1.input ,return a list of two elements ,have you tried :   model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[m1.input[0], m1.input[1] , inputC], outputs=output)

Comment: i tried that with inputs[0] and inputs[1] but didn't work